# Is it possible to send multiple points with descriptions using Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I often find myself needing to send somebody a few geographical locations on a map with a short text description of each point. I've noticed I can send single points using Google Maps like this:

```
https://maps.google.com/?q={latitude},{longitude}
```

And I'm certain I've seen a similar solution that can put some text on that marker as well.

Is there any way, using query parameters to `maps.google.com`, to send a link to multiple custom markers with a description on each marker? If this is not possible I would also appreciate any other suggestions for what I need, not necessarily using Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own personalized google map and share it privately or publicly (like documents in google drive). You can even embed it in your website, blog,...

Head over to https://mapsengine.google.com. I think everything is pretty straightforward.

It got the options for basic things you need. You can add layers, markers, change the map base, draw some lines. It also supports adding driving directions.

What I really like is the possibility of collaboration with others (when planning a trip with bigger group and deciding the routes etc.)

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to add markers at specific coordinates follow these instructions (look at the second image below). First, enter latitude and longtitude coordinates in [available formats](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?hl=en) and do the search (1). You will get your search result listed on the left side, click on it so it will get selected (2). The information window will pop up on the map on the top of the coordinates marker. Click on "Add to map" to add coordinates as your marker (3). You can then modify it as any other marker.

[image]

Comment: That's cool. I can't find a way of adding markers at specific coordinates though, which is really what I need. Any ideas?

Comment: @Codemonkey: I've updated my answer

Comment: After the edit this appears to be a perfect solution! Thanks!